# Trying to implement django pagedown in the admin page

Tags: django, python-2.7, markdown

I have been trying to implement django pagedown feature on my django-admin page for blog posts

I followed the documentation from [Django Pagedown](https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown)

This is what I did

**models.py**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   post_type = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices= (
      ('Mobiles', 'Mobiles'),
      ('Laptops', 'Laptops'),
      ('Laptop_Accesories', 'Laptop_Accesories'),
      ('Tablets', 'Tablets'),
      ('Cameras', 'Cameras'),
      ('Others', 'Others'),
    ), default='Others')
  author = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=False, default="")
  body = models.TextField()
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 200, unique = True)
  publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from pagedown.widgets import AdminPagedownWidget
from blog import models
from blog.models import Entry

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
      description = forms.TextField(widget=AdminPagedownWidget())

class Meta:
    model = Entry
    fields = "__all__"
```

**admin.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from . import models
from django.contrib import admin

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display=("title","created")
     prepopulated_fields = {"slug" : ("title",)}

class EAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = EntryForm
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(models.Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

**I get the error**

> description = forms.TextField(widget=AdminPagedownWidget())
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextField'

Comment: Try using CharField instead?

Comment: Tried that... Did not work

Comment: The error is not there anymore, but the markdown menu did not work

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import new,new_by_viewer
from pagedown.widgets import AdminPagedownWidget
from django.contrib import admin

class story(admin.ModelAdmin):
     formfield_overrides = {
                       models.TextField: {'widget': AdminPagedownWidget },
                       }


admin.site.register(new,story)
admin.site.register(new_by_viewer)
```

try like this , this works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

**Change your admin.py like this**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Entry
from .forms import EntryForm

@admin.register(Entry)
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = EntryForm
     list_display=("title","created")
     prepopulated_fields = {"slug" : ("title",)}
```